# How to edit swiper and its elements with SCSS modules in React?

Tags: reactjs, sass, swiper.js

I have 2-3 different Swipers on 1 page next to each other.
How do i edit ".swiper, .swiper-slide, .swiper-pagination-bullet, .swiper-pagination-bullet-active per-button-prev, .swiper-button-next" in styles.module.scss next to each component?

How to incapsulate each swiper with own bullets and arrows in module.scss?

Everything seem to work, when i add <Swiper **className="xxx_swiper"**> and edit everything in global.scss:

```
.xxx_swiper {
  .swiper {
  }
  .swiper-slide, etc...
}
```

But if if i go like this <Swiper **className={styles.xxx_swiper}**> and try to change inner ellements inside .xxx_swiper_modulehash, nothing works.